# Loop through column then row

Tags: bash, unix, loops, for-loop

I'm sure this has been covered many times but I can't seem to find a good answer...

Here's my file:

```
$ cat myfile.txt
server1     instance1 instance2 instance3
server2     instance4
server3     instance5 instance6
```

What I want:

```
Server: server1, Instance: instance1
Server: server1, Instance: instance2
Server: server1, Instance: instance3
Server: server2, Instance: instance4
Server: server3, Instance: instance5
Server: server3, Instance: instance6
```

I found a way to do it using an if statement within my loop but surely there's a better way...

Thanks!!

Comment: It should be in bash, only with sed and awk? It would be way more trivial in python, and nowdays every server comes with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash can handle this task with ease:

```
#!/bin/bash
# File: format_output.sh
while read server instances
do
    for instance in $instances
    do
        echo "Server: $server, Instance: $instance"
    done
done
```

To use it:

```
$ bash format_output.sh < myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

If awk is allowed, something like

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print "Server: " $1 ", Instance: " $i }' < myfile.txt
```